# How to send PNG file from android and receive it in python

Tags: android, python, sockets, png

I'm trying to send PNG file from my android server to my python client.
The PNG image I try to send is a screenshot, around 4mb tops, usually under 2mb.

android code (sending):

```
                File myFile = new File(imagePath);
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                Log.i("service", "sending file len");
                try {
                    out.write("" +myFile.length());
                    out.flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.i("service:", "waiteing for ok");
                try {
                    msg = in.readLine();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.i("service", "sending file");
                byte[] outBuffer = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
                try {
                    bis.read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length);
                    os = client.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

python code (receiving):

```
    print "waiting for responce's length"
    MSGLEN = int(sock.recv(bufferLen))
    print MSGLEN
    sock.sendall("ok" +"\n")

    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
        chunk = sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, bufferLen))
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)

    dataRecived = ''.join(chunks)
    print 'data receieved'
    print 'writing data to file'

    fileout = open("D:\shots.png", 'w')
    fileout.write(dataRecived)
    fileout.close()
```

The file transfers from the android to my PC, but the file is corrupted.
When I compare it with the original image, almost everything is identical
except some empty lines here and there (not missing information, just empty line like someone added \n) and 1 or 2 big chunks of lines (15 lines or so) are missing.
[Here](https://www.diffchecker.com/siq7ibc3) you can see comparison between the tho files (left-original, right-file after sending).
I don't know why the file transfers corrupted, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coding it as Base64 and sending a simple string. Those missing lines are also part of image data - remember that those are binary.

Comment: ok, I'll try Base64. Just encode my whole file in Base64, send it, and decode in python?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant ;)

Comment: Not really... Still after the decode the file still corrupted. From what i have seen so far, the only difference is some \r where it should not be. I think it is because of the transfer from Unix which uses LF  to Windows that uses CR+LF., but I am not sure yet, still testing

Answer (score 0):

Base64 or Bytestream is what u need

Comment: Bytestream? how do I use it?

Comment: im not familiar with Python but im pretty sure there is a way to stream bytes. Java, or Android : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: tried to use it, same problem with CR+LF and LF (see comment to rasmeta)